# How to directly display "Class" in imenu?

Tags: imenu

imenu only displays "function" by default, "Class" is hidden by default.

As shown below:
[image]

When I need to view "Class", I have to type "Class" and press Enter, which is troublesome, I hope there is a way to display "Class" directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can find `imenu` is not designed to make this configurable for the user. However, by looking a little into the code, we find that we can achieve it using the following code:

```lisp
(defun my-imenu-class ()
  (interactive)
  (imenu (imenu-choose-buffer-index "Jump to class: "
                                    (alist-get "Class"
                                               (imenu--make-index-alist)
                                               nil
                                               nil
                                               'string=))))
```

You can use it via `M-x my-imenu-class`

Of course, you can also create a keybinding for the command.